# Magento 2 create widget container to display in admin end while selcting widget position

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have a requirement in Magento 2 to create a new custom container , so that while adding a new widget from admin end , under the select container section it should come as an option. Mainly my requirement is to create a container for home page.

Please check the attachment for reference.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

To not edit Magento files, I need to write a mini module.

Create the following folders :

- app\code\MyCustom
- app\code\MyCustom\CustomWidget

To register the module, create a **registration.php** file in the **app\code\MyCustom\CustomWidget** folder with the following code :

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MyCustom_CustomWidget',
    __DIR__
);
```

Now that we have a module folder, we need to create a **module.xml** file in the **app\code\MyCustom\CustomWidget\etc** folder with the following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="MyCustom_CustomWidget" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

We need to create a widget.xml file, where there will be a new position, in the **app\code\MyCustom\CustomWidget\etc** folder with the following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="new_products" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" is_email_compatible="true"
            placeholder_image="Magento_Catalog::images/product_widget_new.png" ttl="86400">
        <containers>
            <container name="content.new">
                <template name="grid" value="default" />
                <template name="list" value="list" />
            </container>
        </containers>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Now we need to create a position for your custom theme
**app\design\frontend\package\theme\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="main">
            <container name="content.new" label="New Container"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The result of such
[image]

Comment: I tested this solution, but didn't work

Comment: You are using Catalog New Products List or Catalog Products List?

Answer (score 4):

You can actually simply do this by adding a `label` attribute to any container in your layout xml. This way it is available for all widgets.

If you want it on the homepage you can add it to a `cms_index_index.xml` file in the layout folder of your theme or module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="name.of.container" label="Label text in the backend dropdown" after="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Update: Doesn't work for widgets that have the `containers` parameter set... Then you have to add the container to the widget.xml as well.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create the following folders:

app\code\MyCustom\CustomWidget

2) To register the module, create a registration.php file in the app\code\MyCustom\CustomWidget folder with the following code:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MyCustom_CustomWidget',
    __DIR__
);
```

3) Now that we have a module folder, we need to create a module.xml file in the app\code\MyCustom\CustomWidget\etc folder with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyCustom_CustomWidget" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

4) Now we need to create a default.xml app\code\MyCustom\CustomWidget\frontend\layout\default.xml with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="new_container" label="New Container" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The new container is ready to use.
Thanks