# Change Products per Page on Grid Default Value using custom layout xml - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, category, layout

For some specific categories we would like to change the default value for `Products per Page on Grid Default Value`. By default it's set to 24.

In our custom theme we create a custom page_layout with the following code. But sadly it does not work, it still use the default value 24. What are we missing here?

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="2columns-left"/>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
            <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
                <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">23</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

**Edit:**

When we create a `Custom Layout Update` for the specific category, it does work well with the following code. But we prefer to add it to the category layout itself, instead of creating a custom. layout update for each category. How can we achieve that?

Custom Layout Update code:

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
                <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">23</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Please provide your complete code along with the file path and try this solution. : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/371078/82670

Comment: Have you checked the solution below, or did you encounter any errors?

Comment: @Msquare Thanks! Not yet, will test it asap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Please try below code**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
      <plugin name="page_limit_custom_product" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Toolbar" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
   </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin**

**Toolbar.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin;

class Toolbar
{

 protected $_coreRegistry;

 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 ) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
 }

 public function afterGetAvailableLimit(
   \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
   $result
) {
    $category = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');
    //you can replace with your code.
    if ($category->getCustomContentPosition()) { // you can update condition 
       $result = [];
       for ($i = 6, $k = 0; $k < 5; $i = $i+5, $k++) {
         $result[$i] = $i;
       }
    }

    return $result;
  }
}
```

**Here, you have to return valid array values that support pagination; otherwise, it takes default values. You can modify the dynamic array logic or pass your static array into the plugin array above.**

**OUTPUT**
[image]